# How to specify return type in an async Python function?

Tags: python, types, python-asyncio, mypy

In TypeScript, you would do something like

```ts
async function getString(word: string): Promise<string> {
   return word;
}
```

How can I do the same in Python? I tried the following:

```
async def get_string(word: str) -> Coroutine[str]:
    return word
```

And got this traceback:

```
TypeError: Too few parameters for typing.Coroutine; actual 1, expected 3
```

So `Coroutine` expects 3 types. But why? And what should they be in this case?

This is also specified in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Coroutine), but I still don't understand

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The example [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Coroutine) shows what the three types are:

> ```
> from typing import List, Coroutine
> c = None # type: Coroutine[List[str], str, int]
> ...
> x = c.send('hi') # type: List[str]
> async def bar() -> None:
>     x = await c # type: int
> ```

1. what you'd get back if you sent a value;
2. what value you can send; and
3. what you'd get it you awaited it.

It also links to the [Generator definition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator) with more examples, and a slightly clearer definition:

> ```
> Generator[YieldType, SendType, ReturnType]
> ```

In your case I'd guess `[None, None, str]`, as you only care about the awaitable value.

Answer (score 7):

Even question is older, I think it still misses a clear explanation since it can be quite mind-blowing for typescript developers to grasp the concept.

```
async function getString(word: string): Promise<string> {
    return word;
}
```

unlike in typescript in python you generally don't explicitly write return type for a coroutine it's implicitly known from using the async keyword that the return type will be Coroutine

```
async def get_string(word: str) -> str:
    return word
```

long story short:

```
async main():
    result = get_string() #result has inferred type of Coroutine[Any, Any, str]
    awaited_result = await get_string() #awaited_result has inferred type of str
```

Answer (score 2):

You would type it as:

```py
async def get_string(word: str) -> str:
    return word
```

And it is implied as a `Coroutine[Any, Any, <return_type>]`:

```py
reveal_type(get_string)  # Revealed type is "def (word: builtins.str) -> typing.Coroutine[Any, Any, builtins.str]"
```

The reason why `Coroutine` takes 3 type parameters is because it is analogous to a `Generator` (whose type parameters are the yield, send, and return types), but the Python equivalent of TypeScript’s `Promise<T>` would be `Future[T]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use the `Awaitable` type since an async function returns an awaitable:

```py
from typing import Awaitable
# for Python 3.9 and above, use:
# from collections.abc import Awaitable


async def get_string(word: str) -> Awaitable[str]:
    return word
```